OFII France validation problem
If I have a long stay visa for 1 year as salaried and the contract is expire before coming to France. So the OFII when validating my visa will check with the company? Is there any way to validate my visa while I have no contract?

How is the contract “expiring” before you even started to work? What are you planning to do in France if you don't have a work contract? If you have a work via but no work, getting the validation sticker from OFII is only one of the problems you face.

So what is the answer , it was offer and expired before coming because the visa is delayed for some reasons

You last comment doesn't exactly clarify the situation. Do you have a job or not? The job was contingent on getting the visa and you lost it because the consulate was too slow? In any case, if do not intend to take up the job or do not have one, you should not use the visa.
